# Apply JSON groups to TextFields or Selects based on a JSON Value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, material-ui

I have a bunch of JSON groups pulled from an API. Each group contains 1 or more `questions` objects. I need to append each question to a textField with its corresponding `response` in either a MUI TextField or Select, which needs to be decided based on the `QuestionType` value.

Below is how I am trying to get data to display to a TextField. The TextFields are being populated with `[object Object]` as they are now.

```
const [questions, setQuestions] = useState("");

const fetchQuestions = async () => {
   setQuestions(
      await fetch(`/fiscalyears/FY2023/intakes/${params.id}/details/questions`)
            .then((response) => response.json())
   );
};

useEffect(() => {
   fetchQuestions();
}, []);

...

{questions["question_groups"]?.map((row) => (
   <TextField
      fullWidth
      multiline
      className="text-field"
      value={row?.questions || ""}
      variant="outlined"
      margin="normal"
      label={row["GroupName"]}
   />
))}
```

Here is an example of my JSON. In reality, there could be 20 groups within `question_groups`

```
{
   "question_groups": [
      {
         "GroupName": "DDD",
         "questions": [
            {
               "Question": "1. Do you need a drink?",
               "QuestionType": "Select",
               "Response": null,
               "Choices": [
                  "Yes",
                  "No"
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "GroupName": "FED",
         "questions": [
            {
               "Question": "2. What do you want to drink?",
               "QuestionType": "Text",
               "Response": null,
               "Choices": [
               ]
            },
            {
              "Question": "3. Do you want something to eat?",
               "QuestionType": "Text",
               "Response": "I would like steak",
               "Choices": [
               ] 
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
}
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it doesn't make sense to initialise `questions` as a String. Try an object.

```
const [questions, setQuestions] = useState({});
```

Also, it's not clear that you are actually assigning the results of `fetchQuestions` to `questions`; Assuming you get all the questions you need from a single call, I'll assume you do this with `setQuestions(response.json())` or similar.

If you are in control of the JSON structure, I would change it, but assuming you can't, then, how I would map these to alternate between `Select` and `TextField` would be something like this:

```
const App = () => {
    //... assume you have a state called `questions`
    //populated with your JSON object
    
    //create a component for each type
    const TextQuestion = ({question}) => {
        return(
            <div>
                <TextField //with your question and any necessary props
                />
                <TextField //with your answer
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    const SelectQuestion = ({question}) => {
        return (
            <div>
                <TextField //with your question text
                />
                <Select //with your answer options
                />
            </div>
        )
    }

    //map the array of question_groups, then map the array 
    //of questions in each group and return one of your
    //component types depending on the value of QuestionType

    const questionComps = questions["question_groups"].map((group, i) => {
        return group["questions"].map((question, i) => {
            return question["QuestionType"] === "Text" 
            ? <TextQuestion key={`${i}${question.Question}`} question={question}/>
            : <SelectQuestion key={`${i}${question.Question}`} question={question} />
        })
    })
    //render the collection of question components
    return (
        <div>{questionComps}</div>
    )
}
```

Comment: I have changed the JSON example in the question to better reflect the real data I am working with. In my API response, GroupName ``FED`` has 7 questions. I have also clarified what I mean when I need it to apply to both select's and textFields.  I need each question to display in a textField and its corresponding response displayed underneath it should either be a textField or a Select.  I need the ``response`` field to display even if the JSON value  for ``response`` is null.

Comment: I also get the following error message on ``questionComps`` : ``Err msg: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')``

Comment: I've update the answer to reflect the clarification on needing to display question and answers but the principle is the same. If your questions are undefinded, you have another issue and should research how to properly call your api and assign the results to `questions`. I tested by using your JSON object and it maps to the screen as expected.

Comment: I have one more question for you.  How would you style the them?  I have been applying padding and margins to the textFields but they are not spacing out.  They are sticking together with no spacing on any side of the text fields.  I added class to the textFields in ``TextQuestion`` and ``SelectQuestion`` to no avail.

Comment: I generally use bootstrap grids - `container`, `row`, `col` pattern and then add bootstrap classes for margin and padding if needed. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/